# How to get most sold products in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

My database structure:

```
products
-- name
-- price
-- qty

orders
-- user_id
-- status ... etc

order_product
-- order_id
-- product_id
-- qty
-- product_price_after_discount ( nullable )
```

I need to get most sold products with `total_sells_of_product`  when:

- order `status == 'approved'`
- If there is a `product_price_after_discount` ignore the originall product price and count this.

MY wrong shut:

```
  $topSellingProducts = Product::selectRaw('
                            products.id,
                            products.trade_name,
                            products.company_name
                        ')
                        ->leftJoin('order_product','order_product.product_id','=','products.id')
                        ->where('status','approved')
                        ->groupBy('products.id')
                        ->orderByDesc('total_sales')
                        ->get();
```

Comment: But why does the price make a difference if you are trying to fetch the "most sold" products? I don't see you select the price column anyway

Comment: and should the "most sold" calculation consider the `qty` parameter? for example, if in one order a product has been ordered with `qty` of 100. Will it be considered 100 times or once?

Comment: @HTMHell no no once time, but 100 should * with the price to get the  product_total_sold_price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to consider the quantity in the order when calculating the most sold product:

```
DB::table('products')
    ->select([
        'products.id',
        'products.trade_name',
        'products.company_name',
        DB::raw('SUM(order_product.qty) as total_sales'),
        DB::raw('SUM(IFNULL(product_price_after_discount, products.price) * order_product.qty) AS total_price'),
    ])
    ->join('order_product', 'order_product.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->join('orders', 'order_product.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
    ->where('orders.status','approved')
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->orderByDesc('total_sales')
    ->get();
```

And if you want to consider every product in an order once, then replace `SUM(order_product.qty) as total_sales` with `COUNT(*) as total_sales`.

Comment: Last question Pls is there any effect if I use model instead of (DB::table) ?

Comment: Generally speaking you should use the model, but in this case where you only select some attributes and you have some raw queries it probably doesn't matter.